# Send key stroke to chromedriver, using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am planning to use keyboard shortcuts to drive chromedriver; although I can't find a suitable example.

I load chromedriver as driver.remote object in selenium python; so I can access the elements, and so far it works fine; I can send keys to an element.

Although I do not see how you can actually send browser shortcuts though; the driver.remote does not have a sendkey function; just the elements has it.

So if I want to open a menu shortcut to do any action, I can't. Is there a way to do so, or it is out of the scope of Selenium per se?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot use keys combinations with `chromedriver`. What exactly you want to perform? Which shortcuts?

Comment: Trying to open a new window, new tab, save page, load page. I did try to send these key shortcut with "body" selected but even in that case, the application won't get the command. I can only send text to textfield in the web page itself, not the browser

Comment: `Save page` you mean save `HTML` page source?

Comment: Yes, save as the browser would save, when I use the "save" menu command

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use key combinations with `chromedriver`, but you can try some approaches to perform required actions:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('/path/to/your/local/file.html') # To load page
with open('/path/to/your/local/file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source) # To save currently opened page HTML source code to local file
driver.execute_script('window.open('https://google.com', 'new');') # To open Google page in new tab/window
```

Comment: Thanks; this solve my load and save file; although I can't access the other functionalities of the browser app. It is curious to me that Selenium never expanded the range of operation to the container that actually run the webpage. There are other options of course; like opening a subprocess and call the keyboard shortcut via shell (I am on OSX); but it is not the same as just calling the webdriver. Thanks for the reply!